# JavaEE 7 with JPA (Hibernate) and JAX-RS (RestEasy)

Tags: java, jpa

below is a working example of code in which you can create car colors and cars using these colors with XML POST messages. And request all cars and colors formatted in XML using a GET message. I am running this on WildFly 8.2. The code is working as expected, I would like to know if there are any enhancements possible. Can it be done simpler? Better?

First the business requirements:

- Users must be able to create colors. A color has a name and an a
  status which can be active or passive.
- Users must be able to create cars. A car must have a name and an
  existing active color.
- Users must be able to change the status of the color from passive to
  active and from active to passive, except if there are cars using
  that color.
- Users must be able to request all colors and all cars.

And the technical requirements:

- All input and output should be presented using xml messages.
- All errors in the post messages should be catched with a meaningful
  exeception.

Then for the code. I created two classes for Car an Color, annotated for JPA and XML.

Color.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Color.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Color c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Color.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Color c WHERE c.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Color.findActiveByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Color c WHERE c.isActive = true AND c.name = :name")
})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Color implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private boolean isActive;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "color")
    @XmlTransient
    private List<Car> cars;

    public Color() {
        cars = new ArrayList<>();
        isActive = true;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void isActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

}
```

Car.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Car.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Car c")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "color")
    private Color color;

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

I created a JAXRS Configuration class.

JAXRSConfiguration.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath(value = "resources")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

Resource classes for Color and Car.

ColorResource.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.Wrapped;

@Stateful
@Path(value = "color")
public class ColorResource {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Wrapped(element = "colors")
    public List<Color> get() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Color.findAll", Color.class).getResultList();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response post(final Color color) {
        if (color.getName() == null) {
            return ErrorResponse.create("Name of color not provided");
        }
        List<Color> existingColors;
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Color.findByName", Color.class);
            query.setParameter("name", color.getName());
            existingColors = query.getResultList();
        if (existingColors.size() != 1) {
            em.persist(color);
            return Response.ok(color, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
        }
        Color existingColor = existingColors.get(0);
        if (color.isActive() == false && !existingColor.getCars().isEmpty()) {
            return ErrorResponse.create("Cannot set isActive to false while cars exist with that color");
        } else {
            existingColor.isActive(color.isActive());
            em.merge(existingColor);
        }
        return Response.ok(existingColor, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    }

}
```

CarResource.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.Wrapped;

@Stateful
@Path(value = "car")
public class CarResource {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager em;
    @GET
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Wrapped(element = "cars")
    public List<Car> get() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Car.findAll", Car.class).getResultList();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response post(Car car) {

        Color color = car.getColor();
        if (color == null) {
            return ErrorResponse.create("Color not provided");
        }
        List<Color> existingColors;
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Color.findActiveByName", Color.class);
        query.setParameter("name", car.getColor().getName());
        existingColors = query.getResultList();
        if (existingColors.size() != 1) {
            return ErrorResponse.create("Supplied color does not exist or is not active");
        }
        car.setColor(existingColors.get(0));
        em.persist(car);
        return Response.ok(car, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    }

}
```

And finally a helper class to generate XML error responses.

ErrorResponse.java:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public final class ErrorResponse {

    public static Response create(String message) {
        Document xmlDocument = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            xmlDocument = builder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = xmlDocument.createElement("error");
            rootElement.appendChild(xmlDocument.createTextNode(message));
            xmlDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ErrorResponse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(xmlDocument).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
    }

}
```

I tried to keep my pom.xml as simple as possible.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>junkpackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpaandxml</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jpaandxml</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Color**

Why does `Color` needs to hold a `List <Car>` which is just empty and can't be filled. As it doesn't make sense remove it.

A `Color` object should know nothing about a `Car` object. It shouldn't care if a `Car` exists which has the `Color` as property. If the it is necessary to know, if a given `Color` is used by a `Car`, this should be done with the help of another object or a query over the existing cars.

**ColorResource**

You should be consistent with the style you use. One time you are checking `condition == false` and one time you use the `Not` operator `!condition`.
Variables should be declared near to their usage. If you do this at initialisation or separately is a matter of taste, but you should be consistent with it.

> ```
> List<Color> existingColors;
>     Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Color.findByName", Color.class);
>     query.setParameter("name", color.getName());
>     existingColors = query.getResultList();
> ```

should be

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Color.findByName", Color.class);
query.setParameter("name", color.getName());
List<Color> existingColors = query.getResultList();
```

changeing the condition

> ```
> if (existingColors.size() != 1) {
> ```

to

```
if (existingColors.isEmpty) {
```

makes the meaning of the condition clearer.

if you `return` in an `if` statement, the `else` part isn't necessary and can be removed. This also saves horizontal spacing and makes the code more readable.

```
Color existingColor = existingColors.get(0);
if (!color.isActive() && someValidationObject.isColorUsed(existingColor)) {
    return ErrorResponse.create("Cannot set isActive to false while cars exist with that color");
} 
existingColor.isActive(color.isActive());
em.merge(existingColor);
return Response.ok(existingColor, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
```

**CarResource**

Getting two times the color of the car is not necessary, it won't change. The same about declaration and use of a variable and the `isEmpty()` like above applies to this `post()` method. You should also rename the variable `existingColors` to `existingActiveColors` to make it more meaningful.

```
public Response post(Car car) {

    Color color = car.getColor();
    if (color == null) {
        return ErrorResponse.create("Color not provided");
    }
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Color.findActiveByName", Color.class);
    query.setParameter("name", color.getName());
    List<Color> existingActiveColors= query.getResultList();
    if (existingActiveColors.isEmpty()) {
        return ErrorResponse.create("Supplied color does not exist or is not active");
    }
    car.setColor(existingActiveColors.get(0));
    em.persist(car);
    return Response.ok(car, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
}
```

Comment: Color has a JPA ManyToOne annotation and is filled with the list of cars. It is even used in the ColorResource to check if there are no cars with that color before deactivating it.

Comment: Car.id is used by JPA. Car.name is used in the REST transaction

Comment: The CarResource.post() method does not create an ErrorResponse. If you post a xml message via REST like <car><name>Audi<name><color><name>Red</name></color></car>. This is intended behavior.

Comment: Sorry for that "bad" review. Had been on my phone. Updated answer.